# Best way to display clickable links inside UILabel using Monotouch

Tags: url, xamarin.ios, uilabel, hyperlink, detection

When developing using the Objective-C language I was able to use one of these solutions (Both not available for Monotouch):

- [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)
- [Fancy UILabels](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/)

When researching for some information I could find Miguel's implementation in the TweetStation application:

- [TweetView](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/UI/TweetView.cs)

But at that time, he wrote a small parser for detecting links.
As I didn't find any kind of special UILabel implementation for Monotouch, I would like to know from you:

What would be the best way I should follow to present clickable links inside a UITableViewCell's UILabel text using Monotouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've open sourced my TTTAttributedLabel bindings for MonoTouch that you can use to get links in your labels.

- https://github.com/lipka/MonoTouch.TTTAttributedLabel

Example:

```
TTTAttributedLabel label = new TTTAttributedLabel ();
label.Text = new NSString ("I love Tink");
label.AddLinkToURL (new NSUrl ("http://tinkapp.com/"), new NSRange (7, 4));
label.Delegate = new LabelDelegate ();

...

class LabelDelegate : TTTAttributedLabelDelegate {
    public override void DidSelectLinkWithURL (TTTAttributedLabel label, NSUrl url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Clicked URL: {0}", url.ToString ());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project I already implemented such control, but due to NDA it's impossible to publish it as open source.

Make your own MonoTouch-native subclass of `UILabel` and community will regard you for your work.
Sources of `TTTAttributedLabel` and classes `NSMutableAttributedString`, `CTStringAttributes`, `CTParagraphStyleSettings` will help you.

Comment: Thank Maxim for your answer. I ended up creating my own UIAttributedLabel following Miguel's implementation. I did it because I am with a short deadline and so I will keep this question opened until creating a better solution following your tips.

Comment: Hi @georgepiva , Can you provide me your own UIAttributedLabel code?